# Download files from Content Builder UI

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I have checked documentation at [Content Builder](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/content_builder/getting_started_with_content_builder/) and haven't found a clue if it's possible to download files (in my case images) in **bulk** from Content Builder UI. Is there any button to allows this?

The only possible ways to download assets from Content Builder I can figure out are

1. Copy image URL and save it as image
2. REST API

But none of these methods provides an easy way to bulk download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to download images (or other documents) in bulk from the content builder UI. The only way to do this right now would be programatic, using the API.